# Creating separate graphics

Tags: plotting

I am using the command lines:

```
data = Import["file*.txt", "CSV"]
ListLinePlot[data]
```

to plot lists of points.

As you can notice, my file name is `file*.txt`.
I use that star because I have multiple lists of points to plot.

The problem is that the command from above creates a single graphic, where the points from each file are colored differently.

How can I create a single graphic for each file?
For example if I have 3 files (`file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`) there should be 3 idependent graphics as an output.

Comment: `ListLinePlot@*Import[#,"CSV"]&/@FileNames["file*.txt"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mathematica an iteration over lists can be produced by clever use of operators such as `/@` (Map) or `@@` (Apply), so you could write:

```
data = Import["file*.txt", "CSV"]
ListLinePlot /@ data
```

The result will be a list, that contains the different ListLinePlots.

Maybe in your case its easier to work with `For`-loops, if you want to add additional commands like `Export`.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
data = Import["file*.txt", "CSV"]

For[i = 1, i <= Length[data], i++,
  plot = ListLinePlot[data[[i]]];
  Print[plot];
  Export[ToString[i] <> ".pdf", plot]
]
```

The following aproach dont imports everything at once, it imports every single file separatly inside the `For`-loop. The wildcard `*` is used before this happens with `FileNames`.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
files = FileNames["file*.txt"]

For[i = 1, i <= Length[files], i++,
  data = Import[files〚i〛, "CSV"];
  plot = ListLinePlot[data];
  Print[plot];
  Export[FileBaseName[files[[i]]] <> ".pdf", plot]
]
```

Comment: I think your last suggestion should be your first, but otherwise good. +1

Comment: @Pickett You are right, i just changed that.

Comment: One might also use `Scan[]`: `Scan[Block[{data = Import[#, "CSV"], plot}, Print[plot = ListLinePlot[data]]; Export[FileBaseName[#] <> ".pdf", plot]] &, FileNames["file*.txt"]]`